# How do I stop/fix a process (tracker-extract) from using an extreme amount of memory and causing system hangs?

Tags: gnome, 19.04

The process tracker-extract, running from usr/lib/tracker/tracker-extract, is hanging my PC shortly after I log in by skyrocketing memory usage until the system is rendered unusable. What can I do to stop the process, or fix/diagnose the issue? Stopping the process seems to get it to stop eating up memory, but this is only for this session. Killing the process causes it to spawn again, and continue this behavior.

Specifications:
Ubuntu 19.04
16 GB Memory
i7-4790k

EDIT: Managed to stop it, so I could actually type out a post.

Comment: you can follow this to [disable tracker from startup](https://gist.github.com/vancluever/d34b41eb77e6d077887c).

Comment: @SirajusSalekin That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**